# ' \ '-Invalid character constant?

Tags: java

I need to do this:

```
while (result2.charAt(j) != '\'){
    
}
```

I get an error saying: `Invalid character constant`.

Why? And how can I get over it?

Answer (score 9):

The backslash is a special character and it needs to be escaped with another backslash. Like this:

```
while (result2.charAt(j)!='\\'){

}
```

Comment: Will it be considered as '\'?

Comment: @Unknown user - yes, it will.

Comment: Thank you very much guys.
How can I get these kind of information without bother you here? :-)
does java have something somewhere for these stuff?

Comment: @Unknown You can go to the Java Tutorials. For example in http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html you can see what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use `'\\'`. It's because backslash is used in escape sequence like `'\n'`. With a single `\` the compiler have no way to know.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to escape the backslash. Try

```
while (result2.charAt(j)!='\\'){

    }
```

Comment: I want to compare it to a backslah.

Comment: @Uknown user: Yes. we understand. This is the solution. Try it.

Comment: `charAt()` returns a `char`, not a `String`, so you cannot call `compareTo()` on it. So your second suggestion is broken.

Comment: @Asaph. Whoops, thank you very much for catching my mistake. I removed the incorrect advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it I think,

So you need to do

```
while(results2.charAt(j)!='\\')
{
}
```

I think that's the solution I think

Answer (score 0):

you need an extra character '\'

```
" " " == " \" "


" \ " == " \\ "
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this similar error in Eclipse for Android although for different situation, and I just figured out that in Java you cannot enclose a string (multi-character word) in single quotes.
So you need to have like -
`"sampleword"`
strings enclosed in double quotes rather than single quote to get rid of such error
thought I could just share it here for others to refer..

Answer (score 0):

Same error here, but using unicode character representation.

005C is backlash character. Need to escape it: "\u005C" .

Example:

```
str = str.replace("\\u005C", "'\\u005C'");
```