# primitive char variable initialization with backslash charecter

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘ \ ’-Invalid character constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002366/invalid-character-constant)

In Java, I am trying to initialize a char variable like below, which it is not allowing.

```
char ch = '\';
```

Any reason behind this? It's giving a compilation error.

Comment: you need to escape the backslash. '\\'

Comment: refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html  Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859934/char-initial-value-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to escape it:

```
char backslash = '\\';
char quotation = '\'';
```

The reason is, this `\'` is a single quotation mark.

```
System.out.println(backslash); // prints \
System.out.println(quotation); // prints '
```

Answer (score 1):

Characters like `\`, `"` and `'` hold special meaning. Therefore to use them as character literals, you need to [escape](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Escape_sequences_and_escape_characters#Java) them. They need to be written as `'\\'`, `'\''` and `'\"'` respectively.
e.g. `char c = '\\';`

Similarly, to include them in strings, you need to escape them.
e.g. `String path = "C:\\Program Files\\Java"`