# Invalid character constant in java

Tags: java

```
return (int) (feetPart) + '\' ' + inchesPart + '\''+'\'';
```

Why is the above invalid character constant, this works perfectly in JavaScript. I want to display height in feet and inches and was using this client side, but when I use the same in server side it shows `Invalid character constant`.

Comment: Java is NOT JavaScript!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002366/invalid-character-constant

Comment: Preventing missunderstandings. Javascript is not the same as Java. JS is a script language, developed by Netscape Inc. in the early ninethees. Java is a object orientated language to develop mainingly standalone applications, developed by Sun Inc.

Comment: As mentioned above, java is not javascript and you SHOULDN'T use the same code in java and javascript files. About your question: `'` in java is used for character literals and `"'` is used for string literals. `'\' '` is not a valid character literal in java, while '\'' is. So you should write that statement as `... + "' " ... + "''"`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Why is the above invalid character constant

Because of this part:

```
'\' '
```

That's trying to specify a *character* literal which is actually two characters (an apostrophe and a space). A character literal must be exactly one character.

If you want to specify "apostrophe space" you should use a string literal instead - at which point the apostrophe doesn't have to be escaped:

```
"' "
```

Your whole statement would be better as:

```
return (int) (feetPart) + "' " + inchesPart + "''";
```

Or to use `"` instead of `''` for the inches:

```
return (int) feetPart + "' " + inchesPart + "\"";
```

Note that it's not even clear to me that the original code would do what you wanted if it *did* compile, as I suspect it would have performed integer arithmetic on `feetPart` and the character...

Your code would have been okay in Javascript, because there both single quotes and double quotes are used for string literals.